# java streams - how to flat all values from map of collections using condition on the key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map. Let's say

```
Map<Long, List<MyObj>>
```

I want to create a long array where of all MyObj where the key (long) is found in another set()

```
anotherSet.contains(long)
```

using java stream.

I tried

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .filter(e->anotherSet(e.getKey()))
   .flatMap(e.getValue)
   .collect(Collectors.toList);
```

But it doesnt even compile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had a few syntax errors.

This should produce your desired `List` :

```
List<MyObj> filteredList = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(e->anotherSet.contains(e.getKey())) // you forgot contains
       .flatMap(e-> e.getValue().stream()) // flatMap requires a Function that 
                                           // produces a Stream
       .collect(Collectors.toList()); // you forgot ()
```

If you want to produce an array instead of a `List`, use :

```
MyObj[] filteredArray = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(e->anotherSet.contains(e.getKey()))
       .flatMap(e-> e.getValue().stream())
       .toArray(MyObj[]::new);
```